# Calculate connection between consecutive vertices on the path

Tags: gremlin

Given a graph as the image below described:

[image: subgraph]

**Find all the paths between `person1` and `person5`, then calculate connection between consecutive vertices on the path.**

To illustrate the definition of `connection`, take `person1` and `person2` as an example:
1. `person1` create `comment1` to reply `post2` created by `person2`
2. `person2` create `comment3` to reply `post1` created by `person1`

So, connection between `person1` and `person2` is 2; and that between `person2` and `person5` is `0`.

The path in the graph given above is `[v[person1],v[person2],v[person5]]`:

```
gremlin> g.V('person1').
......1>   repeat(both('knows').simplePath()).
......2>     until(hasId('person5')).path()
==>[v[person1],v[person2],v[person5]]
```

For now, i can only manage to get dsl:

```
gremlin> g.V('person1').
......1>   repeat(both('knows').simplePath()).
......2>     until(hasId('person5').or().loops().is(eq(2))).hasId('person5').path().
......3>       repeat(
......4>         filter(count(local).is(gt(1))).
......5>           sack(assign).by(
......6>             sideEffect(range(local,1,2).aggregate('m')).
......7>             range(local,0,1).
......8>             in('hasCreator').hasLabel('comment').
......9>             out('replyOf').hasLabel('post').
.....10>             out('hasCreator').where(within('m')).count()
.....11>           ).
.....12>           sack(sum).by(
.....13>             sideEffect(range(local,0,1).aggregate('n')).
.....14>             range(local,1,2).
.....15>             in('hasCreator').hasLabel('comment').
.....16>             out('replyOf').hasLabel('post').
.....17>             out('hasCreator').where(within('n')).count()
.....18>           ).
.....19>           skip(local, 1)
.....20>         ).
.....21>       emit().sack().fold()
==>[2,1]
```

But the result is wrong, which is expected to be `[2,0]`. I know that i should not use `aggregate` to filter, but i can't find an proper method according to my knowledge.

The example graph can be generated by :

```
g.addV('person').property(id, 'person1')
g.addV('person').property(id, 'person2')
g.addV('person').property(id, 'person5')

g.addE('knows').from(V('person1')).to(V('person2'))
g.addE('knows').from(V('person2')).to(V('person5'))

g.addV('post').property(id, 'post1')
g.addV('post').property(id, 'post2')

g.addV('comment').property(id, 'comment1')
g.addV('comment').property(id, 'comment2')
g.addV('comment').property(id, 'comment3')

g.addE('hasCreator').from(V('post1')).to(V('person1'))
g.addE('hasCreator').from(V('post2')).to(V('person2'))

g.addE('hasCreator').from(V('comment1')).to(V('person1'))
g.addE('hasCreator').from(V('comment2')).to(V('person2'))
g.addE('hasCreator').from(V('comment3')).to(V('person2'))

g.addE('replyOf').from(V('comment1')).to(V('post2'))
g.addE('replyOf').from(V('comment2')).to(V('post2'))
g.addE('replyOf').from(V('comment3')).to(V('post1'))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After I replace the usage of `aggregate` with `select`, I can get the right answer by now:

```
g.V('person1').
  repeat(both('knows').simplePath()).
    until(hasId('person5').or().loops().is(eq(2))).hasId('person5').path().
        repeat(
            filter(count(local).is(gt(1))).
                sack(assign).by(
                  __.as('orig').
                  range(local,1,2).as('v2').
                  select('orig').range(local,0,1).
                    in('hasCreator').hasLabel('comment').
                    out('replyOf').hasLabel('post').
                    out('hasCreator').where(eq('v2')).count()
                ).
                sack(sum).by(
                  __.as('orig').
                  range(local,0,1).as('v1').
                  select('orig').range(local,1,2).
                    in('hasCreator').hasLabel('comment').
                    out('replyOf').hasLabel('post').
                    out('hasCreator').where(eq('v1')).count()
                ).
                skip(local, 1)
            ).
        emit().sack().fold()
```